# Limit subject length in git --for-each-ref

Tags: git

Is there a way to specify the max length of the subject in the format string for `git --for-each-ref`? I'd have a handy shortcut that lists my branches and the subject of the most recent commit, but I'd like to truncate the length of the subject field so that the output doesn't wrap. On a whim, I tried `%(subject:short)` but git says

```
fatal: %(subject) does not take arguments
```

Comment: While you can use `%(align)` directives to *lengthen* a field, there is nothing to truncate them. You will have to write your for-each-ref as a script using some auxiliary language to truncate the subject lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `bash` to display fields and limit the length with `%.XXs` :

```
git for-each-ref --count=1 --sort='-*authordate' \
--format='%(*refname)|%(*authorname)|%(*authoremail)|%(*subject)|%(*authordate)' 'refs/tags' | \
while IFS='|' read refname authorname authoremail subject authordate
do 
    echo   "Ref      : $refname"
    echo   "From     : $authorname $authoremail"
    printf "Subject  : %.30s\n" "$subject"
    echo   "Date     : $authordate"
done
```

Comment: a very nice decision for those environments where bash is present. We can not ignore the fact that there are some where it's not true - and git still functions there as a CLI tool.